# Arcgis Pro's Eliminate not eliminating selected polygons?

Tags: polygon, arcgis-pro, eliminate

I'm trying to use [Eliminate](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/eliminate.htm) to reduce the number of polygons in my dataset that have a very small area size. As far as i understand the tool, you have to first create a selection in the dataset, and afterwards run the Eliminate tool. What didn't make sense for me, was the fact that the number of selected features didnt add up with the number of features that were returned in the elimination process. I also tried to calculate the area for each of the newly created features, and there were still some as small as the selection i made previously.

below are shown the first selection (47676) and the expected number of returned rows is shown (18.527 vs 20395).
I tried to run the elimination a second time, and the returned rows were still not adding up (18531 vs 18640).

[image]

I read the part that selected polygons that are touching other selected polygons, wont be eliminated. This is however not always the reason for the tool not eliminating parts. 
[image]

IN this example, the yellow polygon is fully contained by the turquise/grey polygon, and should have been eliminated by the tool. All polygons with a value in POLY_AREA smaller than 100 was supposed to be eliminated.

I was therefore wondering if anyknody can explain what is happening here?

Comment: As a boilerplate response, you might check the geometry.  These little polys are often gaps but if you've got an area for them then they aren't that.  If you run an Integrate on a copy of your layer (or better validate the topology if you want to take the time to set one up) with a modest tolerance, does it get rid of the remaining problem polygons?